# PhpStorm specify that current script is included in PHPDoc

Tags: php, class, scope, phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm using PhpStorm and I've got a problem with "Undefined variable" warning. I've got the following class `MyClass.php`:

```
class MyClass{

    private $myVar;

    function __construct(){

        $myclass = $this;
        $this->myVar = new SomeOtherClass();
        include("my_script.php);

    }

}
```

And this is the included file `my_script.php`:

```
<?php
    $myclass->myVar->someFunction();
```

In this case, PhpStorm cannot find `$myclass` and warns. I tried to add PHPDoc:

```
/**
* @var MyClass $myclass
*/
```

But a new warning appears telling me that `$myVar` is `private`.

How can I tell PhpStorm that code in `my_script.php` is inside the scope of my class so It can access class members without warnings?

Comment: /** @var MyClass $localVar */

Comment: `private $myVar;` is the issue -- PhpStorm does not know that `my_script.php` is used inside the class and therefore has access to that private variable. No standard PHPDoc exists that would allow such private variable usage. Ideally -- do not use private var .. or `include` in such way -- code can be written differently. here I may only suggest to use `$this` inside include file (e.g. `$localVar = $this->myVar;`) and typehint `$this` with `/** @var MyClass $this */` there -- *may work*. Other than that only `@property` comes into my mind...

Comment: @LazyOne Just by using `$this` without typehint works without warnings but at the same time PhpStorm won't list class members for auto-completion. I really want to avoid using `$this` and use other variable the way I detailed in the example but I find that all the solutions worsen the code just to make PhpStorm not to throw warnings. Code works like a charm.

Comment: Yes ... but PhpStorm does static analysis ... and does not know how exactly that code will be used during run time. It's better show a warning than skip the error -- base rule here. I gave you the possible solutions that I'm aware. But in general: I would simply avoid wring it this way if I can. Gladly I can.